# How to use array.push inside a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to return the array an array of numbers that conform to the two if statements. The prompt came from leet code, "Self Dividing Numbers", and asks to take in two arguments, a lower and upper bound and check if whether or not each number in that range is divisible by the digits of each individual number.

When I console.log(num) (the commented out portion, I get a correct list of numbers, but not in an array format. To fix this I thought to add a variable, result and return result after pushing an array to result inside the for loop. However when I do this, i only get the first correct term in an array, but not the full array.

How can this be fixed? I've tried moving the return statement in various locations, but that did not fix the issue.

The function should return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15, 22];

```js
function selfDividingNumbers(left, right) {

    for (let j = left; j <= right; j++) {
        let num = j;
        let result = []
        let strNum = num.toString();
        let dividingDigit = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < strNum.length; i++) {
            if (num % parseInt(strNum[i]) == 0) {
                dividingDigit++;
            }
            if (dividingDigit == strNum.length) {
                result.push(num)
                //console.log(num)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
};

console.log(selfDividingNumbers(1, 22));
```

Comment: You need to move your result (both declaration and return) outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

From your expected output, define `result` at the *very top* of the function, and then return only after completely iterating through both loops:

```js
function selfDividingNumbers(left, right) {
  let result = []
  for (let j = left; j <= right; j++) {
    let num = j;
    let strNum = num.toString();
    let dividingDigit = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < strNum.length; i++) {
      if (num % parseInt(strNum[i]) == 0) {
        dividingDigit++;
      }
      if (dividingDigit == strNum.length) {
        result.push(num)
        //console.log(num)
      }
    }
  }
  return result
};

console.log(selfDividingNumbers(1, 22));
```

To be more concise, you might use `.filter` check whether `.every` digit divides evenly:

```js
function selfDividingNumbers(left, right) {
  return Array.from(
    { length: right - left },
    (_, i) => i + left
  )
  .filter((num) => {
    const digits = String(num).split('');
    if (digits.includes(0)) {
      return false;
    }
    return digits.every(digit => num % digit === 0);
  });
}
console.log(selfDividingNumbers(1, 22));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `let result = []` inside your for loop you are telling your code to recreate this array every time your loop iterates, thus, removing all previous results pushed into it. Instead, you need to move this outside your for loop to stop this from happening.

Lastly, you need to `return` only after you're outer for loop is complete, as returning inside your `for` loop will stop the function from running (and thus stop the loop).

See working example below:

```js
function selfDividingNumbers(left, right) {
  let result = [];
  for (let j = left; j <= right; j++) {
    let num = j;

    let strNum = num.toString();
    let dividingDigit = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < strNum.length; i++) {
      if (num % parseInt(strNum[i]) == 0) {
        dividingDigit++;
      }
      if (dividingDigit == strNum.length) {
        result.push(num)
      }
    }

  }
  return result
};

console.log(selfDividingNumbers(1, 22));
```